# objects is noised in camera.ui ursina game engine

Tags: python, ursina

when i put a detailed object in camera.ui by doing this

```
the_object = Entity(model='gun', texture="gun_texture")
```

the gun would be pretty noised

this is how it should've looked like
[image]

this is how it turned out
[image]
my problem isnt the scale obviously my problem
is the black noise

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
the_object = Entity(model='gun', texture="gun_texture", double_sided=True)
```